# :nth-child() Selector

Tags: jquery

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn885612</div>
<div>T.1</div>
<div>T.12</div>
<div>T.13</div>

<script>
  $("div:contains('1') :nth-child(2)").css("background","yellow");
</script>
```

I want to highlight the second child on the "div" which provide "1" 
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
$("div:contains('1')").eq("2").css("background", "yellow");
```

Comment: Thanks for very quickly to reply, Sirwan Afifi

Answer (score 2):

Use the [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) :

```
$("div:contains('1'):eq(2)").css("background","yellow");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cq7q/)